# SwiftUI macOS Scroll a List With Arrow Keys While a TextField is Active

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'd like to use a SwiftUI [`TextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) and a SwiftUI [`List`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) to render a "search box" above a list of items. Something roughly like the search box available in Safari's Help menu item...which provides a search box where you can always enter text while simultaneously browsing through the list of results using the up and down arrow keys.

[image: safari help menu item]

I've played with [`onMoveCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3367875-onmovecommand), [`focusable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/3277076-focusable), and adjustments to the "parent" `NSWindow`, but haven't found a clear and obvious way for the `TextField` to constantly accept input while still being able to navigate the underlying `List` using the up and down arrow keys. The following code allows for either text to be entered in the `TextField`, or list entries to be navigated through, but not both at the same time...

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

  @State var text: String = ""
  @State var selection: Int? = 1

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
      List(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {
          Text("\($0)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have run into the same problem as yours. Wondering if you have any solutions yet? I believe the problem is the TextField takes over all the onMoveCommand, and makes the List unable to react to the event. Not sure if you have made any progress yet, please let me know if you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: I faced the same issue and ended up rewriting the whole view using AppKit instead of SwiftUI to be able to intercept key events and control selection of tableview.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap a NSTextField in a NSViewRepresentable and use the NSTextFieldDelegate to intercept the move up and down keys. You can take a look into my suggestions demo.

[Source of a text field with suggestions](https://github.com/smic/SuggestionsDemo/blob/main/SuggestionsDemo/SuggestionTextField.swift)